# looking for Lightweight inexpensive children's bike (120cm) available in uk

Tags: hybrid-bike, children

I'm looking for Lightweight inexpensive children's hybrid bike (120cm) available in uk for my six year old son. It seems to me at this age they don't need fancy brakes or lots of gears but would really benefit from the bike being as light as possible. But the lighter bikes I've seen always come with the fancy brakes and gears and a hefty price tag.

Does such a bike exist ?

Comment: Voting to close: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve." For a child, weight weenieing is probably not important, given that they'll probably outgrow the bike in a year or so. Just find a used bike or something cheap near by; I doubt a kid would care about weight unless they were an amateur racer.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  We don't do product recommendations here, so any answers are likely be somewhat vague rather than specific models, shops and prices.

Comment: So you think they can produce a lightweight inexpensive bike without the fancy stuff and are just holding out?  You think there is no cost to a light frame and wheels?

Comment: As it stands I'd vote to close.  What about editing the question to make it less about the product and more about the features of kids bikes?

Comment: Consider second hand bikes - older ones tend to be built without the bulky style of flash modern eye-candy bikes.  They will weigh about the same though, will just look thinner.

Comment: When I say lightweight I dont mean super light but the standard low-end bikes are really heavy ! It does matter to kids because the more weight the more effort required to pedal, and it also matters when they are not actually riding them, i.e lifting the out of garden shed. I was hoping there was a company not so well known that took on this problem to create lighter bikes, concentrating on lightness rather than features - I think that is a fair question.

Comment: @Criggie -  'They will weigh about the same though, will just look thinner', thats pointless then.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the kids aren't the ones with the money, so some of the design of a bike is to appeal to the adult with the cash.  When I was a kid, single speed raleigh 20 was common, as were BMX.  You had to be pretty lucky to have a three speed, and only super rich people had ten speeds.   So the excess of gears is appealing mostly to adults.

If 120 cm is the height of your six year old, then that's about 10 cm above "average" so you're looking at a bike with 20" wheels.  Your son will be too small for a 26" wheel bike at this age, so expect this bike to be adequate till about the age of 10-11.  At that point he will be tall enough for a 26" wheel size but a smallish frame. Then somewhere between 15 and 17 he'll have stopped growing taller and that will be about the time to measure for a proper adult's size frame.

The point of all that?  Your purchase will have 5 years of use by your son at most.  So spending silly money on a specially lightweight kid's bike is a waste.  example: google for "carbon frame kids bike" and see how few there are.

Kids do tend to be a little rough on their toys as well - a lightweight frame will not endure being dumped, dropped, dubbed-on or used as a step ladder, as well as a "more robust solid bike"

There's no need to do this:

[image: No need to do this]

Because:

[image: WHOOO FAST!]

Comment: They do definitely exist, "[light kids bike](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=light+kids+bike)" found [a BMX]( http://www.apollobikes.com/bikes14/neo/neo-20-boys) that looks fairly affordable. Racing BMXs are lighter but a lot more expensive. Steer clear of the intermediate wheel sizes between 406 and 559, they're a specialty product and hard to get tyres/parts for.

Comment: Is that available in UK or just Australia ?

Comment: @paultaylor  "that" ?  being the badly photoshopped road bike mockup ?   Focus on what the boy wants, not what you want for him.

For a significant percentage of kids its all about the colour, no more no less.

Comment: @Criggie 'that' being the apollo bike in the comments above. Sure, of course Im going to get what the boy wants, but my other boy  who not a great cyclist complains he cant cycle up many hills, and usually get off and  pushes so I was trying to help the other one out

Comment: @paulTaylor Have you considered a trailgator or a single-wheel tow-along?     http://www.trail-gator.com/ and something like http://www.trademe.co.nz/994232592

Comment: Yes we have one of those, but he can ride himself now doesnt need that anymore.